# ffmpeg loop through directory tree, output to identical tree in different root, only process files once

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I would like ffmpeg to continuously loop through one directory structure looking for *.webm files and then convert them to mp4 when found, outputting them to an identical sub directory structure under a different path.  Sub-directories/files are added to the tree automatically.  I can do this manually, but my scripted attempts failed, I was using an ionotify event script to look for the new directories and re-running the conversion script, but it will not run continuously.  I also do not want to process a file again once it has been converted.

I was using this invoked with each inotify:

```
find /opt/media/ -name "t_str_*.webm" -exec bash -c \
'ffmpeg -loglevel panic -acodec libopus -i $0 -strict experimental -movflags faststart ${0/webm/mp4}' {} \;
```

I have the following directory structure, the subdirectories are alphanumeric.

Source:

```
parent1
 - AAAAAA
   - file1.webm
 - BBBBBB
   - file2.webm
 - CCCCCC
   - file3.webm
 - ZZZZZZ
   - file4.webm
```

Destination:

```
parent2
 - AAAAAA
   - file1.mp4
 - BBBBBB
   - file2.mp4
 - CCCCCC
   - file3.mp4
 - ZZZZZZ
   - file4.mp4
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what is your exact problem? The `find` command doesn't do anything? Add error messages to your question if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

This script looks for a new directory inside `parent1` and if there is a new file that has an extension of `*.webm` it then runs the `ffmpeg` that you have posted against it and create the same directory structure and transfer to `parent2` with the `*.mp4` extension.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find /opt/media/parent2 -type f -name '*.mp4' > parent2_files.txt

fifo="${TMPDIR:-${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR:-/tmp}}/fifo.$$"
trap 'rm -rf "$fifo"' EXIT
mkfifo "$fifo" || exit

check_file() {
  find /opt/media/parent1 -type f -name '*.webm' -exec sh -c '
    for f; do
      f=${f/parent1/parent2}
      f=${f%.webm}.mp4
      echo "$f"
    done
  ' _ {} + | grep -Fvwf parent2_files.txt
}

monitor() {
  while read -r events file; do
    if [[ $events == CREATE && $file == *.webm ]]; then
      return
    fi
  done
}

inotifywait -mrq --format '%e %f' -e create /opt/media/parent1 > "$fifo" & pid=$!

monitor < "$fifo"
kill "$pid"
wait

while read -ru 9 parent2; do
  mkdir -p "${parent2%/*}"
  parent1=${parent2/parent2/parent1}
  parent1=${parent1%.mp4}.webm
  ffmpeg -loglevel panic -acodec libopus -i "$parent1" -strict experimental -movflags faststart "$parent2"
done 9< <(check_file)

"$0"
```

The default directory structure.

```
/opt/
└── media
    ├── parent1
    │   ├── AAAAAA
    │   │   └── file1.webm
    │   ├── BBBBBB
    │   │   └── file2.webm
    │   ├── CCCCCC
    │   │   └── file3.webm
    │   └── ZZZZZZ
    │       └── file4.webm
    └── parent2
        ├── AAAAAA
        │   └── file1.mp4
        ├── BBBBBB
        │   └── file2.mp4
        ├── CCCCCC
        │   └── file3.mp4
        └── ZZZZZZ
            └── file4.mp4
```

If new directories is added in `parent1`

```
/opt/
└── media
    ├── parent1
    │   ├── AAAAAA
    │   │   └── file1.webm
    │   ├── BBBBBB
    │   │   └── file2.webm
    │   ├── CCCCCC
    │   │   └── file3.webm
    │   ├── GGGGGG
    │   │   └── file8.webm
    │   ├── NNNNNN
    │   │   └── file9.webm
    │   ├── PPPPPP
    │   │   └── file7.webm
    │   ├── TTTTTT
    │   │   └── file6.webm
    │   ├── XXXXXX
    │   │   └── file5.webm
    │   └── ZZZZZZ
    │       └── file4.webm
```

After the script.

```
/opt/
└── media
    ├── parent1
    │   ├── AAAAAA
    │   │   └── file1.webm
    │   ├── BBBBBB
    │   │   └── file2.webm
    │   ├── CCCCCC
    │   │   └── file3.webm
    │   ├── GGGGGG
    │   │   └── file8.webm
    │   ├── NNNNNN
    │   │   └── file9.webm
    │   ├── PPPPPP
    │   │   └── file7.webm
    │   ├── TTTTTT
    │   │   └── file6.webm
    │   ├── XXXXXX
    │   │   └── file5.webm
    │   └── ZZZZZZ
    │       └── file4.webm
    └── parent2
        ├── AAAAAA
        │   └── file1.mp4
        ├── BBBBBB
        │   └── file2.mp4
        ├── CCCCCC
        │   └── file3.mp4
        ├── GGGGGG
        │   └── file8.mp4
        ├── NNNNNN
        │   └── file9.mp4
        ├── PPPPPP
        │   └── file7.mp4
        ├── TTTTTT
        │   └── file6.mp4
        ├── XXXXXX
        │   └── file5.mp4
        └── ZZZZZZ
            └── file4.mp4
```

- The idea behind this script was taken from [Bash FAQ117](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/117)